# EventLogReader and EventRecord: Where's the Message?

Tags: c#, event-log

I want to query the Application Event Log on a remote machine and I resorted to using the `EventLogReader` rather than the `EventLog` because it takes way to long to find the events I need with the `EventLog`.  However, even though it finds the events much faster with the `EventLogReader`, I can't figure out where the heck the info I need is on this object... especially the message.

```
    public static void Load()
    {
        string query = "*[System/Provider/@Name=\"SQLSERVERAGENT\"]";

        EventLogQuery elq = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, query);
        elq.Session = new EventLogSession("x.x.x.x");
        EventLogReader elr = new EventLogReader(elq);

        _logEntries = new List<SqlEventEntry>();

        EventRecord entry;
        while ((entry = elr.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {
            var Message = entry.???
            // I want process the message in the event here,
            // but I can't find a property anywhere that contains the message??
        }
    }
```

Comment: Again event viewer to the rescue. Is there one or more `entry.EventData` properties (either an enumerable called `Data` or just multiple named properties)? I'm stabbing in the dark a little, but you can also open eventvwr.msc, open a random event, and look at the XML view.

Comment: @lc. I just figured it out and posted the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, it's too bad there no documentation on this in MSDN. Sorry for only stabbing in the dark :-P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sigh... It's the `FormatDescription()` method.  I didn't see it because I was only looking at the properties.